# No toma mi argumento de año de una forma de herencia simple

Tags: python-3.x, herencia

Cuando trato de tomar el valor de la herencia de "year" al querer mostrarlo con una nueva función  no me toma el argumento correcto.

La superclase es

""""

```
class coche():      
    def __init__(self, nombre, tipo, year ):
        self.nombre= nombre
        self.tipo=tipo 
        self.year=year


    def __str__(self):
    print ("%s es un coche de tipo %s del año %s \n"  % (self.nombre, self.tipo, self.year))
ibiza19= coche("Ibiza","Comercial","2019")
```

"""

El resultado del **str** es : Ibiza es un coche de tipo Comercial del año 2019

Sin embargo el momento de heredar a una subclase el argumento de nombre si lo toma correctamente pero el argumento "year" no

"""

```
class decompeticion(coche):
    def __init__(self,nombre, year, tipo_competicion, escuderia):
        coche.__init__(self, nombre, year, "decompeticion")
        self.tipo_competicion=tipo_competicion
        self.escuderia=escuderia

    def show_competencia(self):
    if self.tipo_competicion == "F1":
        print ("%s es un coche de competicion del año %s "  % (self.nombre, self.year))
        print("Compite en la %s donde son monoplazas, pertenece a la esuderia %s \n" % (self.tipo_competicion, self.escuderia))

z1round= decompeticion("Z1round",2011,"F1","Mclaren")
```

"""

El resultado es el siguiente: Z1round es un coche de competicion del año decompeticion
Compite en la F1 donde son monoplazas, pertenece a la esuderia Maclaren

Gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, por favor edita la pregunta y coloca el código como texto en lugar de la imagen. Revisa [ask] para que tu pregunta tenga mejor alcance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu superclase coche tiene el constructor con parámetros (nombre, tipo, year).

Y donde pasas valores al constructor de coche está mal el orden de los parámetros -> (self, nombre, year, "decompeticion") y por tal razón, imprime "decompeticion" en lugar del año.

Lo correcto sería **(self, nombre, "decompeticion", year)**

```
class decompeticion(coche):
    def __init__(self,nombre, year, tipo_competicion, escuderia):
        coche.__init__(self, nombre, "decompeticion", year)
        self.tipo_competicion=tipo_competicion
        self.escuderia=escuderia
```